# Map head nowhere on first time

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, coordinates

I put a map into my iOs app and I setted it in this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D cord = {.latitude = 44.508473, .longitude =  11.375828};

    [self.myMap setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(cord, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.005, .005)) animated:YES];


    AddressAnnotation * annotazione = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] init];

    [annotazione setCoordinate:cord];
    [self.myMap addAnnotation:annotazione];
}
```

and AddressAnnotation.m:

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
    coordinate = coord;
}
```

It works but first time I open map's view it shows a zone near the Antartica sea (pin head to coordinates but map shows Antartic sea zones) and closing and reopening map's view it shows exactly my pin.

How can I show map zoomed on Pin at first opening?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this code. I would probably just define a `coordinate` property for your `AddressAnnotation` and let the compiler synthesize the appropriate setter and get rid of the custom setter, though that's probably unrelated to the problem you describe ... It's just easier to do it that way, it ensures that the annotation's `coordinate` will conform to KVO, etc.

I might suggest that you define your view controller to be the delegate of the map view and then implement `regionDidChangeAnimated`:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"%s %f, %f %d", __FUNCTION__, mapView.region.center.latitude, mapView.region.center.longitude, animated);
}
```

It might be useful to know what the `region` is getting set to and maybe you can reverse engineer what's going on.

But, bottom line, the problem is unrelated to the code you included in your question and the issue undoubtedly rests elsewhere.

---

By doing this in your project, I saw the following log:

```
2013-03-30 23:11:12.326 iBo[25408:c07] -[POIMapController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] -47.422141, 0.000000 0
2013-03-30 23:11:12.328 iBo[25408:c07] -[POIMapController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] 44.508473, 11.375828 0
2013-03-30 23:11:12.328 iBo[25408:c07] -[POIMapController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] -47.422141, 0.000000 0
2013-03-30 23:11:12.329 iBo[25408:c07] -[POIMapController mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:] -47.422141, 0.000000 0
```

So, clearly your setting the region is taking place, but there's something else which is resetting the region after that happens. Doing a little playing around, I discovered that this behavior only manifests itself when using auto layout. If you turn off auto layout, this behavior goes away and it works like you'd expect.

Alternatively, I noticed that if you moved your code to set the region out of `viewDidLoad` (which is quite early in the view creation process (after the view are created, but before they appear), and put it in `viewDidAppear`, it works.

Comment: nothing useful... NSLog return "2013-03-25 18:46:55.938 Hackathlon[23887:c07] -[MappeController viewDidLoad] nan, nan
" writing line in viewdidload method but pin works right, simple, at first opening, map zoom to nowhere!

Comment: @Matte.Car That's frustrating, I'm sure. Your log statement suggests, though, that you put that log statement in `viewDidLoad`, and I was suggesting you put that in `regionDidChangeAnimated`. Still, the problem doesn't rest in the code listed in your question. If you could upload the code someplace, I'd be happy to take a look. But the small snippet in your question is fine. (I tested it in my own project and it worked ok.)

Comment: I just discovered a very strange thing: in my app, map appear after some table views and it has that trouble, starting app directly from that screen it works right!

Comment: @Matte.Car Thanks for uploading your project. I put in the logging of `regionDidChangeAnimated` and see that your region setting is happening, but there is some auto layout driven setting of region that takes place, too. You can either turn off auto layout, or move your setting of the region to `viewDidAppear` (not `viewDidLoad`, not `viewWillAppear`). See my updated answer.

Comment: Disabling auto layout I can't manage 3.5" or 4" displays so I'll change viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear!

Comment: @Matte.Car You need to turn on "springs and struts" of the autosizing settings. On the size inspector in IB, look at the autosizing settings and you'll see you can control whether it is to grow/shrink with the size of the view or not. For example, for your map view, you'd check all of those options (all four margins fixed, can grow width, can grow height).